# WPF DataGrid column wrapping

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with 4 columns. The first three have `Width="Auto"`, whereas the last has `Width="*"` to fill the remaining space. I do not want a horizontal scrollbar so I have disabled.

[image: Example]

When the program is resized to a certain amount of width, the above situation happens (only the text of the last column gets wrapped). This doesn't look that bad yet,
but when you reduce the window width even more (in which there isn't any space anymore to render the right column), the column with 'wwwwwwwwwwwwwww...' still doesn't wrap it's text and everything becomes white as the right column keeps wrapping to infinity (no space). Now, I expected this problem to go away by introducing a minimum width to the right most column, but instead it results in that column being rendered (partially or fully) outside of the visible area.

It works somewhat as expected when I do the third column also as `Width="*"` but this results in crippling the width of the last column significantly (which I don't want). I tried to set it to `Width="0.1*"` (or anything along these lines) with a minimum width instead, but I get an infinity exception from the datagrid.

This is driving me nuts and I'm not seeing a way out of here to achieve what I want. In short, all I want is the text of the columns to wrap to the available width of the datagrid. The last column should have the width preference.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{Binding HasValidSelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, IsAsync=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                                        CanUserResizeRows="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource CenteredCheckBoxStyle}" x:Key="CenteredReadOnlyCheckBoxStyle">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>                
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Test First" 
             Binding="{Binding First, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredReadOnlyCheckBoxStyle}"
             EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredReadOnlyCheckBoxStyle}" >                        
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Test Second" 
             Binding="{Binding Second, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredReadOnlyCheckBoxStyle}"
             EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CenteredReadOnlyCheckBoxStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test Third" Binding="{Binding Third}"
             EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridEditingTextBoxStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridToolTipDataGridCellStyle}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,6"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test Fourth" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Fourth}" 
             EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridEditingTextBoxStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridToolTipDataGridCellStyle}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,6"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you provide all your grid

Comment: Forgot it @Cedric, check again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a horizontal scrollbar, and it sounds like you want the third and fourth columns to autosize (and wrap if necessary), then don't use `Width="Auto"`.  It seems to me that you would want a fixed column width for the first two (something like `Width="100"`, then for the third and fourth columns use something like `Width="40*"` and `Width="60*"`respectively.  (Or set them to whatever ratio you want)  In addition, you could set a `MinWidth` and/or a `MaxWidth` to control the expansion of the columns.

To enable the wrapping, you'll just need to add an `ElementStyle` to the `DataGridTextColumn`.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check1" Binding="{Binding Check1}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check2" Binding="{Binding Check2}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="40*" MaxWidth="200">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="60*" MinWidth="200">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>                     
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I already use a wrapping text column (it works, I've tested it). Width=20 is not ideal as there are column headers (which need around 100px, depending on the language) Two width with the `*` in it works, but the third column isn't that important and it would mean that a lot of space is wasted. I pretty much want the last column to have the most width available, while retaining a minimum width for all columns.

Comment: @Areius, WIdth=20 was just an example since it just looks like they are checkboxes.  I guess I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish.  If the third column isn't that important, then you could set a `MaxWidth` on column 3 to prevent it from expanding past a certain width, and a `MinWidth` on column 4 to keep it from getting too small...

Comment: I currently have it somewhat working as expected by introducing a MinWidth of 50 on all columns, combined with a MaximumWidth on the third column while having both the third and fourth column's width on *. It's not perfect (as the width of the third column can be too large or too small for some languages, but it's better than the default way (i.e., overflows outside of the window). Unfortunately, it isn't possible to set the MaxWidth to SizeByHeader or SizeByCells.

Comment: @Areius, Maybe not, but I suspect you could calculate the width of the text in the column header (or column field) yourself and set it that way.  You would have to decide if the result is worth the effort though.